# Osm2pgsql don't create tables

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, osm2pgsql

I'm trying to convert planet.osm to postgresql on debian.

```
sudo -u postgres dropdb osm
sudo -u postgres createdb osm
sudo -u postgres  psql -d osm -c 'CREATE EXTENSION postgis; CREATE EXTENSION hstore;'
nohup sudo -u postgres osm2pgsql -c -d osm --multi-geometry  --cache-strategy dense -C 4000 planet-latest.osm&
```

There are no errors, osm2pgsql writes that it creates tables, but there are no any tables in database:

```
sudo -u postgres psql osm
psql (9.5.3, server 9.1.22)
Type "help" for help.

osm=# \d+
                           List of relations
 Schema |       Name        | Type  |  Owner   |  Size   | Description
--------+-------------------+-------+----------+---------+-------------
 public | geography_columns | view  | postgres | 0 bytes |
 public | geometry_columns  | view  | postgres | 0 bytes |
 public | raster_columns    | view  | postgres | 0 bytes |
 public | raster_overviews  | view  | postgres | 0 bytes |
 public | spatial_ref_sys   | table | postgres | 4360 kB |
(5 rows)
```

This is nohup.out file:

```
NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_point" does not exist, skipping
NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_point_tmp" does not exist, skipping
Setting up table: planet_osm_line
NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_line" does not exist, skipping
NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_line_tmp" does not exist, skipping
Setting up table: planet_osm_polygon
NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_polygon" does not exist, skipping
NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_polygon_tmp" does not exist, skipping
Setting up table: planet_osm_roads
NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_roads" does not exist, skipping
NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_roads_tmp" does not exist, skipping
Allocating memory for dense node cache
Allocating dense node cache in one big chunk
Node-cache: cache=4000MB, maxblocks=512001*8192, allocation method=10
Mid: pgsql, scale=100 cache=4000
Setting up table: planet_osm_nodes
NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_nodes" does not exist, skipping
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "planet_osm_nodes_pkey" for table "planet_osm_nodes"
Setting up table: planet_osm_ways
NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_ways" does not exist, skipping
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "planet_osm_ways_pkey" for table "planet_osm_ways"
Setting up table: planet_osm_rels
NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_rels" does not exist, skipping
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "planet_osm_rels_pkey" for table "planet_osm_rels"

Reading in file: planet-latest.osm

Processing: Node(10k 10.0k/s) Way(0k 0.00k/s) Relation(0 0.00/s)
Processing: Node(20k 20.0k/s) Way(0k 0.00k/s) Relation(0 0.00/s)
Processing: Node(30k 30.0k/s) Way(0k 0.00k/s) Relation(0 0.00/s)
Processing: Node(40k 40.0k/s) Way(0k 0.00k/s) Relation(0 0.00/s)
Processing: Node(50k 50.0k/s) Way(0k 0.00k/s) Relation(0 0.00/s)
```

Disk space doesn't reduce. Where does it write the data?

Comment: How long did you wait? osm2pgsql can take a lot of time, especially if you are importing the whole planet. If you are unsure about your setup then take a smaller file first, e.g. one of the [extracts](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm#Country_and_area_extracts).

Comment: Whole night. Process stops without any messages.

Comment: Are you sure the process really stopped? Did you take a look at dmesg to see if it hasn't been an OOM kill or something similar?

Comment: As I knew just now the machine was rebooted.

Comment: The same with osmosis. 2 hours passed and 0 records in nodes table.   Top command shows 100% CPU load. But what is happening?  No information in console output. Maybe it fills its cache files. But where are they located?

Comment: Please try a smaller file or be more patient. Processing the whole planet is a really heavy, resource-intensive task requiring really good hardware. 2 hours is absolutely nothing.